# How can I pay off my school loans (denominated in dollars) with Euros without an exchange fee?

Tags: loans, foreign-exchange, student-loan, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar

I will soon begin earning an income in Europe and 
paying off school loans in the U.S.
Any way to do this without paying an extra exchange fee?

Comment: I won't answer because I am unsure, but perhaps your loan servicer would accept Euros?  If they are a big bank, they might have a EU arm?

Answer (score 4):

You will always pay exchange fees when you exchange currency. The minimum would the the price arbitrage - the difference between the buy and sell prices.

Shop around and check where the exchange rate is the most favorable for you and go there. Don't just look for "no fees" signs because the fees are still charged, through a less favorable exchange rate. Nothing is free, and currency exchange services included.

You would probably get better rates with wire transfers than with checks or exchanging cash.